# Javascript add onclick event to radio buttons on window load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add an onClick event to radio buttons that will then enable me to call another function (calculateTotal).

I can't edit the HTML, so I'm using 'delegate' to target specific elements. The following code is my attempt, but it does nothing:

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('form').delegate('input[type="radio"]', 'focusin', function () {
  $(this).onclick = function() { 'calculateTotal()' };
  });
};
```

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use ugly `onclick`. You should bind event using jQuery like

Use

```
$('form').delegate('input[type="radio"]', 'click', calculateTotal)
```

However if you are using latest version on jQuery use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('form').on('click','input[type="radio"]', calculateTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click event to all radio buttons on document ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('form input[type="radio"]').on('click', calculateTotal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Click` event use `click` event instead of <strike>focusin</strike>, like this:

```
$('form').delegate('input[type="radio"]', 'click', calculateTotal)
                                          ^^^^^^^
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w1qqu54z/)

> **Note:** If you are using Jquery version >= 1.7. You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .delegate()